# REST resource call from JavaScript

Tags: java, javascript, ajax, rest, backbone.js

I have a web app which has JS code as follows (uses Backbone.JS for the model);

```
var StudentDemographic = BaseModel.extend({
        idAttribute: 'studentId',
        url: 'api/list/student/demographic',
        urlRoot: 'api/list/student/demographic',
        defaults: {
                gender: null,
                age: null,
                dob: null,
        }
});
```

Now, there is a call to Java (REST resource) , which I am unable to understand like how it is called exactly. The Java code (REST resource) looks like;

```
@Path("/list")
public class StudentListResource extends BaseResource {

@GET
@Path("/student/demographic")
@Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
@Override
public StudentDemographic getStudentDemographic(@QueryParam("StudentId") String StudentId) {
}

}
```

My question is how exactly is the mapping there between the JS call to api/list/student/demographic and the corresponding Java method. Is that handled by Java library internally or do I need to look up some configuration in my project? (I am into front-end dev, so not very clear with this backend integration).

Also I am keen to understand the lines in Java code @GET, @PUT, @Override, etc (like what do they mean).

Answer (score 0):

Looks like REST application.

The mapping is done by your web application container (Java EE/Spring/...), exact configuration might vary.
The basic mapping definition is done by @Path annotations(here the class StudentListResource handles request going to /list and concrete method getStudentDemographic then handles "relative URL" /student/demographic, thus together /list/student/demographic. This URL is the relative to your web application, that I assume is called "api" (or at least is mapped to /api/**)

@GET annotation just says that it handles only HTTP GET request, similarly @PUT, @POST etc

@Consumes and @Produces specifies that the input and output is expected to be JSON, which is then mapped to Java objects, the input to the method is taken from query (@QueryParam)

@Override is just java language annotation indicating that this method is overridden from super class, but do not have special meaning for mapping.

Comment: Thx a lot for the answer...My project uses EJB...So I assume it is handled by the EJB container...But is there some config like xml where this mapping would be defined ?

Comment: what kind of config file are you searching for? :) Annotations are the way how to map HTTP requests (based on URL and HTTP method) to Java methods. If you are curious how returned Java object is serialized to JSON - either it is transformed in "straight-forward" way (member with name X to Json property with name X) or there can be also different annotations.